# Blend doesn't generate sample data for VM

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, expression-blend-4

In Blend 4, i am trying to generate sample data source from my VM class. The class has a property that returns observablecollection of an interface and another property with observablecollection of a class. When generating sample data source, Blend generates data for the class property but not the interface. Is there a way around this? My code absolutely requires to have the interface, but at the same i want to able to see the sample data generated for design time.

Comment: I have the same issue, my VM has an interface property, and Blend doesn't show the properties in the binding window either.

Comment: Can you please show an example of the class?

Comment: @Michael S. Scherotter: `public class PartialViewModel<M> { public M Model {get; private set;} }` and then my DataContext is `public class MyVM { public PartialViewModel<IDataInterface> Partial {get; private set;} }` and of course `public interface IDataInterface { string Stuff {get;set;}}` And my goal is to see the Partial.Model.Stuff property in blend. But Stuff doesn't show up, and as the original question mentioned doesn't get sample data either!

Comment: Since you are creating a ViewModel of an interface, blend cannot instantiate the object. Therefore, it cannot display the properties and also; it cannot generate a list of sample data because it cannot instantiate the interface (it needs a concrete class). Therefore, you will need a concrete class as Michael showed in his code. However, I believe that for your design, first replace the interface in your ViewModel with the "ConcreteDataInterface" class, this should give you access to the information inside. Once you have finished the design, you can once again revert to using the interface

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that Blend doesn't know what kind of object to create as the concrete implementation of IDataInterface.  I would suggest creating two design-time data sources, one for the MyVM and one for the concrete IDataInterface implementation:

```
namespace SilverlightApplication1
{
    public interface IDataInterface 
    { 
        string Stuff { get; set; } 
    }

    public class PartialViewModel<M> 
    { 
        public M Model { get; private set; } 
    }

    public class ConcreteDataInterface : IDataInterface
    {
        public ConcreteDataInterface()
        {
            this.Stuff = "Concrete Stuff!";
        }

        public string Stuff {get;set;}
    }

    public class MyVM 
    { 
        public PartialViewModel<IDataInterface> Partial 
        { 
            get; 
            private set; 
        } 
    }
}
```

and then the XAML would be:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignData /SampleData/MyVMSampleData.xaml}">
      <Grid DataContext="{Binding Partial.Model}" 
            d:DataContext="{d:DesignData /SampleData/ConcreteDataInterfaceSampleData.xaml}">
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Stuff}"/>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: I tried it out, the problem was that I didn't want to assign Partial.Model to the inner grid's DataContext, since I need both the properties of Model and MyVM inside, but temporarily replacing the interface with the concrete class inside MyVM did work (as Johannes suggested)

Comment: Okay, your solution isn't perfect, but I didn't really specify the smaller details, so I'll award the bounty anyway. Thanks again.